# MySQL - Query a date range

Tags: mysql

I have an `orders` table. Imagine it having only 2 columns, `id` and `created_at`.

Imagine I have a data in my `orders` table that looks something like this:

```
id | created_at
01 | 2018-09-29
02 | 2018-09-29
03 | 2018-09-30
```

I want to select all orders within that day.

I can select the records you by using the following query.

```
SELECT created_at AS date, COUNT(id) AS result 
FROM orders
GROUP BY created_at
ORDER BY date
```

This will return:

```
date | result
2018-09-29 | 2
2018-09-30 | 1
```

I want to expand the query above to generate the following result instead: (daterange)

```
date | result
2018-09-15 | 0
2018-09-16 | 0
...
2018-09-29 | 2
2018-09-30 | 1
```

Is this possible? To select a data that is non-existent to generate a date range report?

Comment: its a lot easy to handle this in your application. detect the gap, and then fill the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted the result must be like this:

```
 date       | result
2018-09-01   |    0
2018-09-02   |    0
2018-09-03   |    0
2018-09-04   |    0
....
2018-09-28   |    0
2018-09-29   |    2
2018-09-28   |    1
```

You need to create a table or temporary table for number of days

```
id 
1
2
3
4
...
28
29
30
31
```

And try to query this:

```
SELECT 
    DATE((select CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', MONTH(CURDATE()),'-' ,day))) as Date1, 
        COUNT(o.order_id) 
        as counting from orders as o 
        right join numberofdays d 
        on d.day = DAY(o.created_at) 
        GROUP BY Date1
        ORDER BY Date1
```

I used RIGHT JOIN:

[image: See image]

Hope this might help. Thanks.